# Forbbiden on microservice mapping call using gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, csrf, gateway

I'm using spring cloud gateway to interact with microservices. It runs on port 8000:

```
package com.smdev.gatewayservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator getRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder){
        return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
                .route(p -> p
                        .path("/api/mail/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.dedupeResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "RETAIN_UNIQUE"))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8001"))
                .build();
    }

}
```

MailService controller (running on port 8001):

```
package com.smdev.mailservice.controller;

import com.smdev.mailservice.model.dto.EmailAddress;
import com.smdev.mailservice.model.dto.SendMailDTO;
import com.smdev.mailservice.service.MailService;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Api
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/mail")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", methods = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.OPTIONS})
public class MailSendController {

    private final MailService mailService;

    @Autowired
    public MailSendController(MailService mailService) {
        this.mailService = mailService;
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Send message from 'Contact Us' form")
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "E-Mail send successfully"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid data sent", response = ResponseEntity.class)
    })
    @PostMapping(value = "/feedback", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public void feedback(@Valid @RequestBody SendMailDTO sendMailDTO){
        mailService.sendMessage(sendMailDTO, EmailAddress.FEEDBACK);
    }

}
```

I'm not using any SpringSecurity features beside CORS. When im calling `localhost:8001/api/mail/feedback` manually everything works. But when doing post request to `localhost:8000/api/mail/feedback` from angular FE i'm getting `403 Forbbiden` and also this response: `An expected CSRF token cannot be found`